# Label in tkinter How can I make the text appear without a background?

Tags: tkinter

How can I make the text appear without a background?  It means a clean text, and behind the text the image of the watch is visible[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkvNW.jpg)

Comment: Just set the background of Label with that color. In your case, `Label(text="21", bg="#F30620", ...)`

Comment: There is no way to make that text appear without a background, since `Label` is not supported with transparent backgrounds in Tk.